# Linearity between predictors and dependent variable in a linear model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, assumptions

I run the following linear model in R :

```
lm(formula = NA. ~ PC + I(1/SPCI), data = DSET)
```

The p-value for each predictor is significant, and it works fairly well with respect to most of the assumptions in linear regression, such as:

- Normal distribution of errors.
- High correlation between predicted values and estimated values.
- Homoscedasticity.
- Non-collinearity between the predictors: PC and (1/SPCI) are not correlated at all!

But, digging more into the topic, there's an assumption that fails in my model, and it says:

> Linearity of the relationship between dependent and independent variables.

This kind of contradicts the non-collinearity assumption because, if NA. and PC are highly correlated and NA. and (1/SPCI) are too, then PC and (1/SPCI) are correlated, and this is violating the assumption of non-collinearity.

I think that I misunderstood the assumption, or there's an explanation to this.

Comment: They way I see that assumption is that it refers to the assumption about the linearity of the model, with respect to the dependent variable. In other words, you are assuming that `NA.` is linearly related to `PC + I(1/SPCI)`, not to them individually.

Comment: The multicollinearity is the problem only when the explanatory variables are highly correlated. One way to test this is to use variance inflation factor or condition index.

Comment: In this model, colinearity between the predictors is not a problem, the problem is that (1/SCPCI) and NA. are not correlated, is this really a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add to AdamO's answer, I was taught to base my decisions regarding model assumptions more on whether failing to correct the assumption in some way causes me to misrepresent my data.  For a concrete example of what I mean, I simulated some data in `R` and created some plots and ran some diagnostics using these data.

```
# lmSupport contains the lm.modelAssumptions function that I use below
require(lmSupport)
set.seed(12234)

# Create some data with a strong quadratic component
x <- rnorm(200, sd = 1)
y <- x + .75 * x^2 + rnorm(200, sd = 1)

# There is a significant linear trend
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7972 -0.9511 -0.1312  0.6659  5.8659 

    Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.77981    0.10463   7.453 2.77e-12 ***
x            1.19417    0.09795  12.191  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1.477 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4288, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4259 
F-statistic: 148.6 on 1 and 198 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, when plotting the data, it's clear that the curvilinear component is an important aspect of the relationship between x and y.

```
pX <- seq(min(x), max(x), by = .1)
pY <- predict(mod, data.frame(x = pX))
plot(x, y, frame = F)
lines(pX, pY, col = "red")
```

[image]

A diagnostic test of linearity also supports our argument that the quadratic component is an important aspect of the relationship between x and y for these data.

```
lm.modelAssumptions(mod, "linear")

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.7798       1.1942  


ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
gvlma(x = model) 

                       Value   p-value                   Decision
Global Stat        180.04567 0.000e+00 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Skewness            32.67166 1.091e-08 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Kurtosis            23.99022 9.683e-07 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Link Function      123.35831 0.000e+00 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Heteroscedasticity   0.02547 8.732e-01    Assumptions acceptable.

# We should probably add the quadratic component to this model
mod <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

Let's see what happens when we simulate data with a smaller (but still significant) nonlinear trend.

```
y <- x + .25 * x^2 + rnorm(200, sd = 1)

mod <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.59701 -0.77446  0.03546  0.80261  2.75938 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.30500    0.07907   3.858 0.000155 ***
x            0.99934    0.07402  13.500  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1.116 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4793, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4767 
F-statistic: 182.3 on 1 and 198 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If we examine a plot of these new data, it's pretty clear that they are well-represented by just the linear trend.

```
pX <- seq(min(x), max(x), by = .1)
pY <- predict(mod, data.frame(x = pX))
plot(x, y, frame = F)
lines(pX, pY, col = "red")
```

[image]

This is in spite of the fact that this model fails a diagnostic test of linearity.

```
lm.modelAssumptions(mod, "linear")

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.3050       0.9993  


ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
gvlma(x = model) 

                     Value   p-value                   Decision
Global Stat        34.6428 5.500e-07 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Skewness            0.3355 5.624e-01    Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis            2.0094 1.563e-01    Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      32.1379 1.436e-08 Assumptions NOT satisfied!
Heteroscedasticity  0.1600 6.892e-01    Assumptions acceptable.
```

My point is that diagnostic tests should not be a substitute for thinking on the part of the analyst; they are tools to help you understand whether your substantive conclusions follow from your analyses.  For this reason, I prefer to look at different types of plots rather than rely on global tests when I'm making these sorts of decisions.

Answer (score 4):

The emphasis upon so called assumptions in linear regression modeling is evidence that  pedagogy in the applied fields is not in line with traditional statistical theory. In particular, the aforementioned "straight line assumption" (or non-existence of higher order effects) is completely erroneous depending upon your intended application.

For inference, the test of whether a regression parameter $\beta = 0$ under the null hypothesis, it should be stressed that the $\beta$ need not model the truth, it's just a first order trend indicating the direction (sign) and strength (value) of that association. Such is the case with regression models and the name itself: a simplified "rule of thumb". Smoking is negatively associated with survival, social drinking is positively associated with obesity, etc. are examples of such rules of thumb gleaned from rules-of-thumb regression models.

For prediction, the complexity of a trend can be infinite provided a sufficient quantity of data have been provided for the application. Thus it's moot to ask "is a straight line enough" when we should be asking, "would a fractional polynomial / smoothing spline / etc. do better?" that decision, of course, would be based upon the overall predictive accuracy determined in a split-sample cross-validated independent dataset.

In both cases, making decisions based on visual inspections about the types of models you fit greatly increase the risk of overfitting the trend (committing type I errors in the inference case). I think the answer is to consider exactly what the regression model is intended to do and determine how flexible and robust the model is for that application.